# metaprograming on python Namespace object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to assign all the items into `Namesapce` object dynamically

But it seems not work, how could I get it.

```
export_file={
    "default_value": "{0}_default_value.txt".format(args.cam_ip),
    "msword": "{0}_msword.txt".format(args.cam_ip),
}

args = argparse.Namespace()

for key,value in export_file.iteritems():
    args.key = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
for key, value in export_file.iteritems():
    setattr(args, key, value)
```

Example usage of `setattr`:

```
>>> class Namespace:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 1
...
>>> ns = Namespace()
>>> ns.a
1
>>> setattr(ns, 'a', 9)
>>> ns.a
9
```